# In Android Studio How To Remove Guidelines?

Tags: android-studio

I'm learning Android Studio, so I clicked a few buttons to add vertical and horizontal guidelines, but how to roll back ? In the following image you can see how they look, but I can't figure out how to not show the guidelines ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, select it, make sure it turns blue, then hit "Delete" key to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the guidelines or just go into the **COMPONENT TREE** window below the **Palettes** and delete the guidelines you want.